# Проблема с доступом к объекту страницы. Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, объекты

Нужно получить ID страницы пользователя.

В GreasMonkey удается получить доступ к объекту

```
alert(current.uid);
```

Однако, из собранного расширения chrome доступа к объекту получить не удается, говорит, undefined.

Собственно, вопрос. GM же как то получает доступ к объектам страницы. Как можно реализовать это у себя?

Код:

```
var response = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = '127.0.0.1/stat.php?uid='+current.uid;
response.onload=function(){
                       showMSG(response.responseText); 
                }
        }
    response.onerror=function(){
                showMSG('Ошибка загрузки данных статистики');
                return false;
            }
    response.open('GET',url,true);
    response.send();
                }
```

Comment: А код ревалентный задаче покажите?

Comment: @UserName приложил

Comment: Из GreasMonkey удается получить доступ через простое присвоение. 
Интересует, как можно получить доступ из собранного расширение.

Comment: @UserName, спасибо, сейчас попробую, и скажу. что вышло.

Comment: @UserName, добавил в web_accessible_resources свой скрипт. В итоге всё равно, ругается, current is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ни `content_scripts` ни `background` не имеют доступа к переменным и функциям определенным на `web` странице, так как они выполняются в изолированном окружении.

Для того, чтобы выполнить код в контексте `web` страницы нужно в `manifest.json` определить ключ `web_accessible_resources`. Этот ключ указывает какие скрипты могут выполняться в контексте `web` страницы.

---

Добавляем ключ в `manifest.json`:

`"web_accessible_resources" : ["lib/inject/script.js"]`

Из `content_scripts` встраиваем код на страницу:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');

script.src = chrome.extension.getURL("lib/inject/script.js");

document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Из `script.js` можно выполнять действия в контексте `web` страницы:

```
alert(current.oid);
```

---

Для того, чтобы получить результат работы нужно определить ключ `externally_connectable` в `manifest.json`. Значения этого ключа указывают какие страницы могут связываться с расширением через `runtime.connect` и    `runtime.sendMessage`.

---

Добавляем ключ в `manifest.json`:

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"]
}
```

Отправка сообщения со страницы:

```
// Идентификатор расширения, с которым нужно связаться
var extensionId = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc";

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, {oid: current.oid});
```

В расширении нужно установить слушателя на событие `onMessageExternal`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(

    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {

        if (request.oid) func(request.oid);
    });
```

Это не единственный способ. Можно отправлять данные оперируя `DOM`'ом страницы или [window.postMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication).

---

[Web Accessible Resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) | [externally_connectable](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable) | [Execution environment](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment)